# Adding errorbars to a bar plot with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

im a starter with Python and I wanted to start using it for making plots and statistics at work. So I made some code to create a Bar chart, which works fine for me so far. However, now I want to add error-bars to it and I don't get it to work at all.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


colors = ["r","g","b","y","m","c"]
df = pd.read_excel("Chlorophyll_data.xlsx")

meandf = df.groupby(["Group"], as_index=False).mean()
semdf = df.groupby(["Group"], as_index=False).sem()

# print(df)
# print(meandf[[1]])
chl_a_df = meandf[["Group","Chl_A_0D","Chl_A_2DaT","Chl_A_10DaT","Chl_A_1DaR","Chl_A_3DaR","Chl_A_7DaR"]]
chl_a_stabw = semdf[["Group","Chl_A_0D","Chl_A_2DaT","Chl_A_10DaT","Chl_A_1DaR","Chl_A_3DaR","Chl_A_7DaR"]]
print(chl_a_df)
print(chl_a_stabw)
plt.figure(figsize=[20,10])

chl_a_df.plot.bar(x="Group" )
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend(loc=(1.04, 0.5))
plt.xlabel("Cultivars")
plt.ylabel("Chlorophyll in μg/g freshweight")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Reading through tutorials and documentations, the following code should create errorbars as far as I understand.

```
plt.errorbar()
```

However, I don't really understand how this should work, since I need to give it some data to it? Or do I need to merge my two dataframes first for that?

Best Regards from a total noob and thanks for any help :/

Edit:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Group</th><th>Chl_A_0D</th><th>Chl_B_0D</th><th>Chl_AB_0D</th><th>Chl_xc_0D</th><th>Chl_A_2DaT</th><th>Chl_B_2DaT</th><th>Chl_AB_2DaT</th><th>Chl_xc_2DaT</th><th>Chl_A_10DaT</th><th>Chl_B_10DaT</th><th>Chl_AB_10DaT</th><th>Chl_xc_10DaT</th><th>Chl_A_1DaR</th><th>Chl_B_1DaR</th><th>Chl_AB_1DaR</th><th>Chl_xc_1DaR</th><th>Chl_A_3DaR</th><th>Chl_B_3DaR</th><th>Chl_AB_3DaR</th><th>Chl_xc_3DaR</th><th>Chl_A_7DaR</th><th>Chl_B_7DaR</th><th>Chl_AB_7DaR</th><th>Chl_xc_7DaR</th></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>500</td><td>100</td><td>600</td><td>101,57</td><td>500</td><td>100</td><td>600</td><td>101,57</td><td>500</td><td>100</td><td>600</td><td>101,57</td><td>500</td><td>100</td><td>600</td><td>101,57</td><td>500</td><td>100</td><td>600</td><td>101,57</td><td>500</td><td>100</td><td>600</td><td>101,57</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>400</td><td>150</td><td>550</td><td>131,31</td><td>400</td><td>150</td><td>550</td><td>131,31</td><td>400</td><td>150</td><td>550</td><td>131,31</td><td>400</td><td>150</td><td>550</td><td>131,31</td><td>400</td><td>150</td><td>550</td><td>131,31</td><td>400</td><td>150</td><td>550</td><td>131,31</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>600</td><td>180</td><td>780</td><td>119,34</td><td>600</td><td>180</td><td>780</td><td>119,34</td><td>600</td><td>180</td><td>780</td><td>119,34</td><td>600</td><td>180</td><td>780</td><td>119,34</td><td>600</td><td>180</td><td>780</td><td>119,34</td><td>600</td><td>180</td><td>780</td><td>119,34</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>800</td><td>200</td><td>1000</td><td>121,75</td><td>800</td><td>200</td><td>1000</td><td>121,75</td><td>800</td><td>200</td><td>1000</td><td>121,75</td><td>800</td><td>200</td><td>1000</td><td>121,75</td><td>800</td><td>200</td><td>1000</td><td>121,75</td><td>800</td><td>200</td><td>1000</td><td>121,75</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>400</td><td>100</td><td>500</td><td>82,17</td><td>400</td><td>100</td><td>500</td><td>82,17</td><td>400</td><td>100</td><td>500</td><td>82,17</td><td>400</td><td>100</td><td>500</td><td>82,17</td><td>400</td><td>100</td><td>500</td><td>82,17</td><td>400</td><td>100</td><td>500</td><td>82,17</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>500</td><td>120</td><td>620</td><td>105,01</td><td>500</td><td>120</td><td>620</td><td>105,01</td><td>500</td><td>120</td><td>620</td><td>105,01</td><td>500</td><td>120</td><td>620</td><td>105,01</td><td>500</td><td>120</td><td>620</td><td>105,01</td><td>500</td><td>120</td><td>620</td><td>105,01</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>600</td><td>140</td><td>654,71</td><td>104,04</td><td>600</td><td>140</td><td>654,71</td><td>104,04</td><td>600</td><td>140</td><td>654,71</td><td>104,04</td><td>600</td><td>140</td><td>654,71</td><td>104,04</td><td>600</td><td>140</td><td>654,71</td><td>104,04</td><td>600</td><td>140</td><td>654,71</td><td>104,04</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_cont</td><td>700</td><td>150,3</td><td>627,73</td><td>100,49</td><td>700</td><td>150,3</td><td>627,73</td><td>100,49</td><td>700</td><td>150,3</td><td>627,73</td><td>100,49</td><td>700</td><td>150,3</td><td>627,73</td><td>100,49</td><td>700</td><td>150,3</td><td>627,73</td><td>100,49</td><td>700</td><td>150,3</td><td>627,73</td><td>100,49</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>653,5714286</td><td>143,7214286</td><td>652,5010714</td><td>96,07714286</td><td>653,5714286</td><td>143,7214286</td><td>652,5010714</td><td>96,07714286</td><td>653,5714286</td><td>143,7214286</td><td>652,5010714</td><td>96,07714286</td><td>653,5714286</td><td>143,7214286</td><td>652,5010714</td><td>96,07714286</td><td>653,5714286</td><td>143,7214286</td><td>652,5010714</td><td>96,07714286</td><td>653,5714286</td><td>143,7214286</td><td>652,5010714</td><td>96,07714286</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>673,8095238</td><td>143,9845238</td><td>649,3779762</td><td>93,38095238</td><td>673,8095238</td><td>143,9845238</td><td>649,3779762</td><td>93,38095238</td><td>673,8095238</td><td>143,9845238</td><td>649,3779762</td><td>93,38095238</td><td>673,8095238</td><td>143,9845238</td><td>649,3779762</td><td>93,38095238</td><td>673,8095238</td><td>143,9845238</td><td>649,3779762</td><td>93,38095238</td><td>673,8095238</td><td>143,9845238</td><td>649,3779762</td><td>93,38095238</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>694,047619</td><td>144,247619</td><td>646,254881</td><td>90,6847619</td><td>694,047619</td><td>144,247619</td><td>646,254881</td><td>90,6847619</td><td>694,047619</td><td>144,247619</td><td>646,254881</td><td>90,6847619</td><td>694,047619</td><td>144,247619</td><td>646,254881</td><td>90,6847619</td><td>694,047619</td><td>144,247619</td><td>646,254881</td><td>90,6847619</td><td>694,047619</td><td>144,247619</td><td>646,254881</td><td>90,6847619</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>714,2857143</td><td>144,5107143</td><td>643,1317857</td><td>87,98857143</td><td>714,2857143</td><td>144,5107143</td><td>643,1317857</td><td>87,98857143</td><td>714,2857143</td><td>144,5107143</td><td>643,1317857</td><td>87,98857143</td><td>714,2857143</td><td>144,5107143</td><td>643,1317857</td><td>87,98857143</td><td>714,2857143</td><td>144,5107143</td><td>643,1317857</td><td>87,98857143</td><td>714,2857143</td><td>144,5107143</td><td>643,1317857</td><td>87,98857143</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>734,5238095</td><td>144,7738095</td><td>640,0086905</td><td>85,29238095</td><td>734,5238095</td><td>144,7738095</td><td>640,0086905</td><td>85,29238095</td><td>734,5238095</td><td>144,7738095</td><td>640,0086905</td><td>85,29238095</td><td>734,5238095</td><td>144,7738095</td><td>640,0086905</td><td>85,29238095</td><td>734,5238095</td><td>144,7738095</td><td>640,0086905</td><td>85,29238095</td><td>734,5238095</td><td>144,7738095</td><td>640,0086905</td><td>85,29238095</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>754,7619048</td><td>145,0369048</td><td>636,8855952</td><td>82,59619048</td><td>754,7619048</td><td>145,0369048</td><td>636,8855952</td><td>82,59619048</td><td>754,7619048</td><td>145,0369048</td><td>636,8855952</td><td>82,59619048</td><td>754,7619048</td><td>145,0369048</td><td>636,8855952</td><td>82,59619048</td><td>754,7619048</td><td>145,0369048</td><td>636,8855952</td><td>82,59619048</td><td>754,7619048</td><td>145,0369048</td><td>636,8855952</td><td>82,59619048</td></tr><tr><td>Bd_treat</td><td>775</td><td>145,3</td><td>633,7625</td><td>79,9</td><td>775</td><td>145,3</td><td>633,7625</td><td>79,9</td><td>775</td><td>145,3</td><td>633,7625</td><td>79,9</td><td>775</td><td>145,3</td><td>633,7625</td><td>79,9</td><td>775</td><td>145,3</td><td>633,7625</td><td>79,9</td><td>775</td><td>145,3</td><td>633,7625</td><td>79,9</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Since I don't have your dataset, running your code is a little tricky but two things you could try are the regular [MPL error bars](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-error-bars-to-a-matplotlib-bar-plot/) or the [Seaborn barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

Comment: 1. please provide the `df` (or a working example).  2. please confirm where `stabwdf` is defined. The code is not reproducible without this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this error, I attached a table with data as a test, which resembles the data from the excel file.